# angular cannot enter the http.get function

Tags: angular

This is my method to download data. When I call `getRezerwacje(`), my console shows:

```
1,
4.
```

It seems like it's not entering the `http.get()` function. When I enter the URL in my browser I get data, so the API is working fine.

```
 getRezerwacje() {

      console.log('1');
      this.http.get('http://192.168.0.153:8090/api/rezerwacja/getPrzyjazdy')
      .map(
        (response: Response) => {
          console.log('2');
          const rezerwacje: Rezerwacja[] = response.json();
          this.rezerwacjeService.wczytajRezerwacje(rezerwacje);
          return rezerwacje;
        }
      )
          .subscribe(
          data => console.log(data),
          err => console.log(err),
      );
      console.log('4');
  }
```

Comment: could you show errors that you get

Comment: hey, no errors.

Comment: console only shows 1 and 4

Comment: okay show how you inject the http and rezerwacjeService

Comment: @Injectable()
export class DataStorageService {
  constructor(public http: Http,
              private recipeService: RecipeService,
              private rezerwacjeService: RezerwacjaService,
              private meldunekService: MeldunekService) {
  }

Answer (score 0):

Solved - i was using http library. I switched to new HttpCLient library and it's working back again!